# What test to do when comparing multiple proportions? If Chi-squared, how do I see where differences lie?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, proportion

I have a sample of data in R looking at vendors and I would like to compare the % of vendors which sell a product for each vendor type, as in the table below:
[image: Table describing % of each type of vendorn that sold a food group]

I have further data for which I want to calculate the same sort of proportions, but also for 4 different towns. From an overview it seems like some of the categories are quite different, so I would like to do some sort of statistical analysis. While I could do a Chi-squared, it would also be interesting to know where the differences lie. Please let me know if there are any suggestions, as my stats knowledge is limited to 1st year uni.

Comment: Do you have the raw counts? Or alternatively, the number of vendors for each type? Classical statistical inference, such as tests, confidence intervals, p-values, for *percentages* without this background information is not possible: the difference between "40%" and "60%" could be significant or not, depending on how many individuals (vendors) were asked.